# Why the score is not updating ??? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is a Snake Water Gun Game in python
But My score is not counting
What is the problem

```
import random
```

Importing Random Module

```
chance = 1

human_point = 0
computer_point = 0

print("s for snake , w for water , g for gun ; you can use both uppercase or lowercase characters")

while (chance <= 10):

    lst=["s","w","g"]
    computer_choice=random.choice(lst)

    human_point = 0
    computer_point = 0

    usr = input("Snake, Water & Gun : ")
    usr = usr.lower()

    if usr == computer_choice:
        print("Tie\nNobody get points")
       
    elif usr == "s" and computer_choice=="w":
        print("You Win!")
        human_point = human_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
        
    elif usr == "s" and computer_choice=="g":
        print("You Loose")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
       
    elif usr == "w" and computer_choice=="g":
        print("You Win!")
        human_point = human_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
        
    elif usr == "w" and computer_choice=="s":
        print("You Loose")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
        
    elif usr == "g" and computer_choice=="s":
        print("You Win!")
        human_point = human_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
       
    elif usr == "g" and computer_choice=="w":
        print("You Loose")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")

    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue

        if attempts>10:
            print("Game Over!")

    print("No. of guesses left: {}".format(10 - chance))
    chance = chance + 1

    if computer_point < human_point:
        print("All Over You Win! And Computer Loose")
        print(f"Your score: {human_point} \nComputer's score: {computer_point}")

    elif computer_point > human_point:
        print("All Over Computer Win! And You Loose")
        print(f"Your score: {human_point} \nComputer's score: {computer_point}")

    else:
        print("It Was A Tie")

        print(10 - chance, "no. of guesses left")
        chance = chance + 1
```

But if computer wins the computer score = 1 and my score = 0 and if I win then my score = 1 and computer score = 0

Why it is not counting score

Please Suggest me the answer What I am doing wrong

Please Help

Comment: note that you are incrementing `chance` twice inside the loop. You need to make sure the counts are correct.

Answer (score 3):

You set the score of both you and your computer to `0` at the beginning of your while loop. This would mean that for every iteration, your scores will be `0` so when you do a command such as: `computer_point = computer_point + 1` or `player_point = player_point + 1`, those statements will always evaluate to `0 + 1`, hence why it doesn't actually "update"

Answer (score 3):

you repeated `human_point = 0`, `computer_point = 0` code under `while`.

you should probably erase that part

```
human_point = 0
computer_point = 0

print("s for snake , w for water , g for gun ; you can use both uppercase or lowercase characters")

while (chance <= 10):

    lst=["s","w","g"]
    computer_choice=random.choice(lst)

    human_point = 0      <- erase this part
    computer_point = 0   <- erase this part
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full code you'll need. I removed chance = chance +1 repeating twice and updated the logic to only display the final result if chance = 10. Finally, I moved the human_point = 0 and computer_point = 0 to above the while loop so you don't constantly reset the score.

```
import random

chance = 1

human_point = 0
computer_point = 0

print("s for snake , w for water , g for gun ; you can use both uppercase or lowercase characters")


while (chance <= 10):

    lst=["s","w","g"]
    computer_choice=random.choice(lst)

    usr = input("Snake, Water & Gun : ")
    usr = usr.lower()

    if usr == computer_choice:
        print("Tie\nNobody get points")
       
    elif usr == "s" and computer_choice=="w":
        print("You Win!")
        human_point = human_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
        
    elif usr == "s" and computer_choice=="g":
        print("You Loose")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
       
    elif usr == "w" and computer_choice=="g":
        print("You Win!")
        human_point = human_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
        
    elif usr == "w" and computer_choice=="s":
        print("You Loose")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
        
    elif usr == "g" and computer_choice=="s":
        print("You Win!")
        human_point = human_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")
       
    elif usr == "g" and computer_choice=="w":
        print("You Loose")
        computer_point = computer_point + 1
        print(f"You Choosed {usr} Computer Choosed {computer_choice} ")

    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue

        if attempts>10:
            print("Game Over!")

    print("No. of guesses left: {}".format(10 - chance))
    chance = chance + 1

    if chance == 10 and computer_point < human_point:
        print("All Over You Win! And Computer Loose")
        print(f"Your score: {human_point} \nComputer's score: {computer_point}")

    elif chance == 10 and computer_point > human_point:
        print("All Over Computer Win! And You Loose")
        print(f"Your score: {human_point} \nComputer's score: {computer_point}")

    elif chance == 10 and computer_point == human_point:
        print("It Was A Tie")

        print(10 - chance, "no. of guesses left")
```

Comment: you defined `humain_choice` and `computer_choice` twice which is unnecessary and can provide problems later for the user.

Comment: alright I updated your score thank you for fixing it.